# Printing HUGE PDF batches in order

Tags: pdf, printing, automation

Sorry if this is a little off-topic for regular stackoverflow questions, but we're tearing our hair out on this one. 
We've got a batch of about 3500 3-page PDFs to print (all ok so far) the problem we've got is that it's vital they print in a specific order (ascending by filename). Our spooler seems to randomize the printrun.  Any ideas on a way to either solve this the old fashioned way or point me in the right direction to fix this programatically?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all, I some advice over a techrepublic with regards to a printer setting called 'Print spooled documents first' unticking the box seems to have honoured the order the files were sent.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a PDF library and some simple-ish scripting to turn them into one unholy document. One PDF to rule them all, one PDF to find them, one PDF to bring them all, and in the darkness bind them... so to speak.

Edit: As an easier option, you can get software that will do your evil bidding for you. The simplest/cheapest method I've seen so far is through [PDFSam](http://www.pdfsam.org/?page_id=32). And if you give the developer a Euro (or more, your prerogative) you get a better version. Not sure what's in it apart from encryption though.

Answer (score 1):

With iText (java) or iTextSharp (.net) you can put them all together in the order you want.

I would first take a look at the print spooler, though.